# How to use google secret key in firebase functions to init stripe?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to init stipe as follow:

```
const { defineSecret } = require("firebase-functions/params");
const stripeSecretKey = defineSecret("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY");
const stripe = require("stripe")(stripeSecretKey.value);
```

But I get an error that stripe key is not correct.

Then I tried this:

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(stripeSecretKey.value());
```

and get this error:

> Cannot access the value of secret "STRIPE_SECRET_KEY" during function deployment. Secret values are only available at runtime.

How should I init stipe here?

Comment: The error message is telling you that you can only access secret keys inside the body of your function while it's running.  You can't use them at the global scope of your code as you're doing now.  Review the example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#secret_parameters), which puts the use of `value()` inside the onRequest function.

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a community wiki based on @DougStevenson's comment:

> The error message is telling you that you can only access secret keys inside the body of your function while it's running. You can't use them at the global scope of your code as you're doing now. Review the example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd#secret_parameters), which puts the use of `value()` inside the onRequest function.